# How to get the number of the instances of a struct existing in a running Linux kernel?

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel

Suppose `struct A` is a structure of Linux kernel code, and there may be many instances of `struct A` being created and destroyed in a running Linux kernel, How can I know the number of instances of `struct A` existing right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can't, unless you can see that the structure is only instantiated in a single way (if there is a constructor/factory function).

For structures often used on the stack, there is typically no such function (although it's certainly possible since structure instances can be returned as values).

C doesn't provide any way to do this automatically, you'd have to build it yourself which would require finding all places where instances are created.

Comment: Why not? You may instrument them to be an object and convert all instances to use a special macro / function to construct an object. The question is too broad to see what exactly is an echievemnt of this exercise. But for custom struct it's quite possible, for objects it's also possible.
Ah, your answer is exactly about that.

Comment: You sound like you're talking about C++, and halfway through as if you had no actual comment to post any more but did so anyway. :)

Comment: No, I'm talking about OOP concept which is widely used in Linux kernel.